# Link Button To Each Database Search Result

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching around for days and cannot seem to find the answer to this, so was wondering if perhaps someone here could lend a hand.

I am displaying a list of results from a search through a database and it is displaying each of the results and underneath a Checkout, Return or Edit button. What i am trying to achieve is get the correct values from each search result from the button beneath each result, and then using them on the next page to do the actual checkout. So when the user clicks on the checkout,return or edit button on this page, the values above are stored/sent to the next page ready to be checked out.

If i try with $_SESSION variables, it only give the last value stored. I apologise if this is a simple question its just ive been stuck for awhile now with this and need to get it done :)

I am using mysql instead of mysqli for the time being as its whats my boss wants but we will be updating in the future once he gives me the go ahead.

Thank you for any help, and i apologise for the bad coding as i am still very new to all this.

Thanks again.

```
<?php session_start(); 

include ('conbase.php'); 
  if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
  } else {
      header("Refresh: 0; url=loginfailure.php");
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search Results</title>
<link href="css/calcsearchs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="headDiv" style="background-color:#000"></div>
<div id="picDiv" style="padding-left: 25%; float: left"><a href="index.php"><img  src="images/ogplogo.jpg" /></a></div><div style="float: left; padding-top: 80px; padding- left: 10px"><p><h1>OGPSS Inventory Database</h1><br /><h2>Search Results</h2></p></div>
<div style="clear: both">
<div id="apDiv1">Logged in as:</div>
<div id="apDiv2"><?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['namevar']); ?></div>
<div id="apDiv3"><?php echo date('d-m-Y - H:ia'); ?></div>
<div id="apDiv4"><input name="logoutbutton" type="submit" value="Log Out" style="height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px" /></div>
```

```
<div style="padding-left: 35%">
<form action="confirmcheckout.php" method="post">
<?php


$query = $_POST['searchbox'];
$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemsinstock
        WHERE (`item_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`item_category` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR(`sernum` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`item_id` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`date_added` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`item_location` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`entered_by` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
    // articles is the name of our table

    // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
    // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
    // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

            echo "<p><b>Item S/N: </b>".$results['sernum']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item ID: </b>".$results['item_id']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Name: </b>".$results['item_name']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Date Added: </b>".$results['date_added']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Category: </b>".$results['item_category']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Location: </b>".$results['item_location']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Qty: </b>".$results['item_qty']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Entered By: </b>".$results['entered_by']."</p>";

            echo "<div><form action='checkform.php' method='post'><input type='submit' name='checkoutbut' value='Checkout' style='height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px'/><input type='submit' name='returnbut' value='Return' style='height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px'/><input type='submit' name='editbut' value='Edit'style='height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px' /></form></div></br></br>"; 
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "There are no results to display matching your query.";
    }

} if($query == ''){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then


    $query = $_POST['indexselect'];  
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemsinstock
        WHERE (`item_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`item_category` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR(`sernum` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`item_id` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`date_added` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`item_location` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`entered_by` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
    // articles is the name of our table

    // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
    // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
    // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

            echo "<p><b>Item S/N: </b>".$results['sernum']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item ID: </b>".$results['item_id']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Name: </b>".$results['item_name']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Date Added: </b>".$results['date_added']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Category: </b>".$results['item_category']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Location: </b>".$results['item_location']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Item Qty: </b>".$results['item_qty']."</p>";
            echo "<p><b>Entered By: </b>".$results['entered_by']."</p>";

            echo "<div><form action='confirmcheckout.php' method='post'><input type='submit' name='checkoutbut' value='Checkout' style='height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px'/><input type='submit' name='returnbut' value='Return' style='height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px'/><input type='submit' name='editbut' value='Edit'style='height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px' /></form></div></br></br>"; 
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }

    } 
}
?>
</form>
</div>

<div id="footerDiv"><p align="center">Copyright OGPSS 2014</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Hi again, thanks so much for the help.

This was excatly what i was looking for! The only thing now is im sure im doing something wrong here on the last page where it displays the entry. Using this method im not sure if im putting the $_GET variables in the right place here. When i come to this page, in the text boxes i see undefined indexes where there should the values.

From some examples ive seen this should work but at the same time im sure ive done something wrong here so if you could please show me where?

```
<?php session_start(); 
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    } else {
        header("Refresh: 0; url=loginfailure.php");
        }
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Confirm Checkout</title>
<link href="css/confirmcheckout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="apDiv1"></div>

<div id="topBarDiv"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/ogplogo.jpg" width="119"  height="205" alt="OGPLOGO" /></a></div>

<div id="apDiv3"><h1>OGPSS Inventory Database</h1></div>

<div id="apDiv4"><h3>Confirm Checkout</h3></div>

<form action="checkoutcomplete.php" method="post">

    <div id="mainDiv">Item S/N:</div>
    <div id="apDiv2"><input name="checksnbox" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $_GET['itemsn']; ?>" /></div>

    <div id="apDiv5">Item ID:</div>
    <div id="apDiv6"><input name="checkidbox" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $_GET['itemid']; ?>" /></div>

    <div id="apDiv8">Taken By:</div>
    <div id="apDiv9"><input name="checkusernamebox" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['namevar']) ?>" /></div>

    <div id="apDiv10">Date Taken:</div>
    <div id="apDiv11"><input name="checkdatebox" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo date('d-m-y'); ?>" /></div>

    <div id="apDiv14">Qty Taken:</div>
    <div id="apDiv15"><input name="checkqtybox" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $_GET['itemqty']; ?>" /></div>

    <div id="apDiv12">Item Name:</div>
    <div id="apDiv13"><input name="checitemnamebox" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $_GET['itemname']; ?>" /></div>

    <div id="apDiv7"><input style="height: 27px; width: 85px" name="checkcheckbut" type="submit" value="Confirm" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using form within a form why dont you use `<a>` tag inside a form to do the same..

Comment: Please don't use forms inside forms. Such code is just asking to get broken.

Comment: Also, please stop using `mysql_*`. It's deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using form within a form why dont you use `<a>` tag inside a form to do the same.

```
 echo "<div><a href='confirmcheckout.php?id=$results['id']' method='post'>
       <input type='button' name='checkoutbut' value='Checkout' style='height: 27px; 
       width: 85px; font-size: 12px'/><input type='button' name='returnbut' 
       value='Return' style='height: 27px; width: 85px; font-size: 12px'/>
       <input type='button' name='editbut' value='Edit'style='height: 27px; 
        width: 85px; font-size: 12px' /></a></div></br></br>";
```

**confirmcheckout.php:**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a hidden input with the value of your row as follows, you need to add this to your form

> ```
> <input type='hidden' name='row_id' value='{$results['id']}'/>
> ```

You can later catch it just like any other value being sent in a request
so

```
$id = $_POST['row_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I will certainly try this! I never knew it was bad to have forms inside other forms, i must sort this out. Will def try the hidden input Thanks!

Comment: If the answer was helpful then accepting it as a correct answer would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldnt have a form inside another form. That wont work in any browser and its specificaly forbidden, as you can see in W3C XHTML oficial specification , Section B. “Element Prohibitions”, states that:  ”form must not contain other form elements.” 
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions

Said this, next thing is that you shouldnt have much data in the search result page or in session. The best is to simply pass the id of the element, and perform another search in the next page to retrieve the item with all its necessary data. 
Yo can pass the id whith a hidden field, as @AliTRixx sais, with

```
<input type='hidden' name='row_id' value='{$results['id']}'/>
```

or in a GET parameter, changing form buttom form links, for example

```
<a href ='confirmcheckout.php?id=ITEM_ID'>checkout</a>
```